# nginx-ingress use default upstream 127.0.0.1:8181

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am new with Kubernetes and maybe my question was stupid, but I don't know how to fix it

I create an nginx-ingress deployment with nodePort service using this manual https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:1.9.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: readiness-port
          containerPort: 8081
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /nginx-ready
            port: readiness-port
          periodSeconds: 1
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
```

And service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
      nodePort: 30369
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

And create deployments with service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: landing
  name: landing
  labels:
    app:landing
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: landing
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: landing
        namespace: landing
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: landing
        image: private-registry/landing
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: landing
  namespace: landing
spec:
  selector:
    app: landing
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Then I add ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: landing
  namespace: landing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: landing.site
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: landing
          servicePort: 80
```

But in nginx-ingress POD, I see default upstream backend,

```
upstream default-landing-landing.site-landing-80 {
    zone default-landing-landing.site-landing-80 256k;
    random two least_conn;

    server 127.0.0.1:8181 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s max_conns=0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of cluster is it ? EKS ? Bare-metal ? GKE ? AKS ?

Comment: It's bare-metal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was so stupid :) I have another one ingress in default backend with same host. Delete it and all works fine

Answer (score 0):

That is how an nginx ingress works. There is nothing wrong here.
A default backend is to handle all URL paths which a nginx controller doesn't understand.
So in your case, any request expect landing.site/ would be served by the default backend and be shown a generic 404 nginx error page.

Comment: But all request for landing.site goes to default backend. And how configuration should looks like for nginx to serve all landing.site requests to landing service? In nginx pod there is no different configuration except default upstream backend.

Comment: Okay, could you remove ingressClassName field from the spec section of your ingress resource and apply the config file.

Comment: Remove it, but no change in config /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-landing.conf